# Why Click event got unwired when we append an element in React functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to trigger the click event of a button which was append into the body. but the click event got unwired when we appending an element in the React Functional components..please find the code below,

Code snippet:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  function increaseValue() {
    console.log('click');
    setValue(value + 1);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    var btnElement = document.getElementById('btn');
    document.body.appendChild(btnElement);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="control-pane">
      <div className="control-section modal-dialog-target">
        <div id="btn">
          <button onClick={increaseValue}>Click</button>
          <span>{value}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

If i remove the document.body.appendChild(btnElement); The click event works fine.

**Sample**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ntrkyi-lefq4u?file=index.js,package.json,index.html

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Have posted some feedback on the button.. but for the useEffect, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do in the `useEffect()` but your button isn't working, can be updated to:

```js
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    increaseValue();
  }}
>
  Click
</button>
```

That'll get the increment working.